# Bloomberg - Excel VBA Macro to email Bloomberg <CN> screen via <GRAB>

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I am looking to develop an Excel-Bloomberg macro. The excel spreadsheet will be linked to a Bloomberg Add-In and of course, a Bloomberg Terminal. The objective of the macro is to have a list of securities in column A which we need to gather ‘company news’ for. The objective of this macro is to provide news as a source of backup for equities moving over a price tolerance. The Bloomberg `<CN>` Screen is desired. The macro needs to execute to the `<CN>` (company news) screen of each security listed in column A of the spreadsheet.

The objective for this macro would be to `<GRAB>` (export the screen, virtually print screening, and sending the `<CN>` screen via email)  for any security in column A with a price change of 10% or greater.

For example and for the date of 10/23 the stock of company ‘Yelp’ went down -18%
The news on Bloomberg `<CN>` screen is as follows
http://tinypic.com/r/2qnqgci/8
"Yelp shares Plummet as Quarterly Forecast Misses Estimates"

How could I get this `<CN>` screen to pull through a VBA Macro? and perhaps how could I get the subsequent screen (after clicking on the #1 news story in the image)
http://tinypic.com/r/t6p6o6/8

The macro would look up the stock of YELP on Bloomberg by using the company's CUSIP
which is `985817105 Equity`

A simple formula for reference
To get the last price for current day would be:
`=BDH(985817105 Equity,PX_LAST,20141023)` [all of those values would be cell references, Bloomberg Data History]
alternatively the `=BDP` formula could be used:
`=BDP(985817105 Equity,PX_LAST)` [this Bloomberg Data Point formula only captures current day data]

I have seen some Bloomberg code utilizing keyboard characters to navigate i.e. `<tabr>` & `<GO>` but I am not too familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

```
bg = DDEInitiate("winblp", "bbk")
Call DDEExecute(bg, "<blp-3><home>ID " & bbgkey & "<GO>")
Call DDEExecute(bg, "<blp-3>CN<GO><copy>")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: How could we learn more of these DDE functions? Are there any resources available?