# How to send a email in Bloomberg using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

I want to send an email in bloomberg using VBA.

What I have tried so far:

```
Sub Test()                                                     
bg = DDEInitiate("winblp", "bbk")                               
Call DDEExecute(bg, "MSG " & bbgkey & "<GO>")                   
Call DDEExecute(bg, "90" & "<GO>")                             
End Sub
```

This gets me to the Email Composer in the Bloomberg, but I can't seem to be able to add the address of the person I am sending the email to. How do I do it programmatically?

How do I do it?

Need some guidance to do it.

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: Press `F1` key twice : ask for someone from API group.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's in the Wilmot forum, there's an answer that you can try out.](http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=3&threadid=77392) I am not going to copy that code here. It's also advisable that you get a copy of latest DAPI developer's (you may know the jargon).

In the case you need help, they are pretty nice people always team up to help the clients. But most importantly make sure, the blp.dll add-ins are running well in your machine and connected to the terminal and ofcourse you are logged in using the authorized BB ids.

[This is a related post on sending a screen via GRAB.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26538783/1389394)